# Django: ManyToMany URL in Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I can't add URL my `category title` in homepage. There is my code and error. What i can add instead of `{{ c.get_absolute_url }}`. What i am missing here?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("category_url", kwargs={"slug": self.slug })


class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

views.py

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'products/index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(),
    name='home'),
url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    CategoryProductList.as_view(),
    name='category_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    ProductPageView.as_view(),
    name='product_detail'),
```

index.html

```
{% for product in product_list %}
  <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>

  {% for c in product.categories.all %}
      <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.title }}</a>
  {% endfor %}

  {{ product.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

ERROR

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'category_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'vans'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Comment: You need to show your urls

Comment: Added urls.py @DanielRoseman

Comment: You have no url whose `name=category_url` in your `urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models you call `category_url` but in your urls you have `category_detail`, replace the `get_absolute_url` function for this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("category_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```